# Node.js Express GET request does not work even though the same request with POST works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

GET request return 404 error but POST request to the same url works fine I could not figure out the reason.

this is the server setup:

images.route.js

```js
const express= require('express');
const controllers = require('./controllers');
const router= express.Router();
const upload = require('../../lib/uploads.controller');
router.get('/', (req, res)=> res.send('get request'))
router.post('/', controllers.getAll);

 module.exports= router;
```

route.js

```js
const express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

const albumRoutes = require('./albums/album.route');
 const imageRoutes= require('./images/index');


router.use('/albums', albumRoutes);
 router.use('/images', imageRoutes);

module.exports= router;
```

server.js

```js
let express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  let history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
  
  const userRoute = require('./routes/router');
  
  const app = express();
app.options('*', cors())

  app.use(cors());
app.use(history());


app.use(express.json({limit: 
'50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: '50mb',
  parameterLimit: 1000000
}));

app.use('/api', userRoute)

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
 app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Connected to port ' + port)
})
```

I have been searching for a solution but I could not find any reason.
I even installed different  REST API apps like postman and insomnia just in case, but it is the same

Comment: You haven't posted any details on how you ping those endpoints so there's no way for us to help you :)

Comment: I am using postman and insomnia alternitavely 

with this url http://localhost:4000/api/images 
but post, put, delete requests work but not get request

Comment: They are both defined at the same place using the standard ways of doing so. From source point of view it looks okay. It's some setup issue, or how you send the get request. Without a fully source code there's no way to help you.

Comment: I figured it out, it was because of history middleware.
thank you any way.